# Use Google API with Sign In With Google

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin

I think I got quite lost in different google docs.
I want to use the new Sign In With [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) to access the [Google sheets api](https://content-sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets) in the name of this user.
On the Google Cloud console I created a Auth 2.0-Client and created an consent screen with spreadsheets allowed.
With the Sign In With Google button I can get an JWT which I try to use on requests to https://content-sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets.

But I get an error: "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22)

But the url in this error links me to an old google docs that are deprecated.
What am I missing ?

If I look into details of the [JWT](https://jwt.io/) I get from Sign in, there is no scope attribute which I would expect to be present to call sheets api, but I don't know how to get it there and if it is really needed.

Comment: You need to use an **Access Token**. You mentioned **JWT**, do you actually mean an OIDC Identity Token? You cannot use that token for that API. Some Google Cloud services use Identity Tokens for authorization, but Google APIs use OAuth Access Tokens.

Comment: Thanks a just got my self confused with the deprecation

Comment: For anyone who also gets confused, thats the correct way: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#the_new_way